# Замена SQL Express на SQL Enterprise

Tags: windows, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

При установленом сервере SQL Express, если ставить полноценный сервер SQL Developer, нужно удалять или что-то делать с Express-ом?

Comment: Оба инстанса могут существовать параллельно. Дадите ему другое имя и все.

Экспресс будет, например, `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` (он по дефолту обычно именует инстанс как `EXPRESS`), а полноценный - `MYSERVER`.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта на выбор:

1. Поставить Developer / Enterprise отдельным инстансом (безымянным, или с любым именем на выбор). Тогда вы сможете подключатся к новому инстансу как `MYSERVER\INSTANCENAME` (или просто `MYSERVER`); к Express - как и раньше, через `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS`.
2. Сделать Edition Upgrade. Эта одна из опций инсталлера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она превратит ваш Express в Developer / Enterprise. Вот только имя инстанса останется старым - `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` - что может вызывать определенные неудобства.